# Creating a bar chart

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset on which I have used the describe() function.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnaQb.png)

Now, I have plotted 2 bar graphs showing subject wise min and max scores in each.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipVRP.png)

Now, I want to plot the min and max marks in a single bar graph subject wise.

How to do this?

Comment: Can you try `stud.describe().loc[['min', 'max']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=False, grid=True)`

Answer (score 0):

**sample df.describe() (just a dummy one):**

```
   Pressure(BP) Nitrogen Dioxide(NO2) PM       10(RSPM) PM.1      2.5(PM2.5)
count 7.000000  7.000000  7.000000  7.000000  7.000000  7.000000  7.000000
mean  151.0000  295.2857  110.4285  184.1428  134.2857  302.5714  303.857143
std   188.3781  101.1001  163.9490  154.8595  156.0883  103.8763  104.387784
min   0.000000  68.00000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  69.00000  69.000000
25%   0.000000  321.0000  0.000000  34.50000  0.000000  323.0000  325.500000
50%   0.000000  326.0000  0.000000  248.0000  69.00000  346.0000  344.000000
75%   349.5000  338.5000  209.5000  322.0000  260.0000  351.5000  353.000000
max   358.0000  354.0000  354.0000  328.0000  351.0000  354.0000  357.000000
```

[image]

Try this:

```
df.describe().loc[['min','max']].T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```